# Can Typescript Enforce Class Types?

Tags: typescript

In the example below, I expected that by declaring variable `c1` as type `Coordinate` that it would be either initialized as instance of `Coordinate` or I would get a compilation error.

#### Typescript:

```js
class Coordinate {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    toString(): string {
        return `(${this.x},${this.y})`;
    }
};

const c1 : Coordinate = {x:1, y:2};             // <=== problem
const c2 : Coordinate = new Coordinate(3, 4);

console.log('c1', c1 instanceof Coordinate ? 'Coordinate' : 'not Coordinate');
console.log('c2', c2 instanceof Coordinate ? 'Coordinate' : 'not Coordinate');

console.log(`c1: ${c1}`);
console.log(`c2: ${c2}`);
```

#### Compilation

The official node `typescript` package transpiles this typescript code without errors or warnings:

```
npx tsc --version
Version 4.0.3
npx tsc
```

#### Actual Output:

```
c1 not Coordinate
c2 Coordinate
c1: [object Object]
c2: (3,4)
```

#### Expected Output:

Either:

1. Line `const c1 : Coordinate = {x:1, y:2};` causes a compilation error, or
2. c1 is coerced into an instance of `Coordinate`:

   ```
    c1 Coordinate
    c2 Coordinate
    c1: (1,2)
    c2: (3,4)
   ```

Is there a way of coding or configuring typescript to behave either of these ways?  I'd prefer a compilator error. I'd like to have cpp-like type enforcement, not duck-typing.

Comment: TypeScript uses structural subtyping, not nominal subtyping, so I don’t think it is possible, but it would be great to hear an authoritative answer. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, Typescript is structurally typed, so in general you want to work with the idea that anything which has an `x` or a `y` is a valid `Coordinate`. However, we can get around that. From [that same link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html),

> When an instance of a class is checked for compatibility, if the target type contains a private member, then the source type must also contain a private member that originated from the same class.

So if we give the class a private member (even if we never use it), like so

```
class Coordinate {
    private _ignore: any;
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    toString(): string {
        return `(${this.x},${this.y})`;
    }
};
```

Then we can never construct it outside of using `Coordinate` directly

```
const c1 : Coordinate = {x:1, y:2}; // Error
const d1 : Coordinate = {_ignore: 0, x:1, y:2}; // Also an error
```

Even `d1` fails, because although it has all of the right field names, the private ones didn't come from the correct class. This allows us to get the nominal behavior of languages like Java or Scala when we want it.

**Note:**

If you're worried about adding a field to a struct, you can also do the same trick with a private member function.

```
class Coordinate {
    x: number;
    y: number;

    constructor(x: number, y: number) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    private _ignore(): void {}

    toString(): string {
        return `(${this.x},${this.y})`;
    }
};
```

This will have the same effect.

Comment: That works, thanks!  Would using a private member function instead of a data member avoid increasing the size of the data structure?  For example: `private _ignore(): void {};`

Comment: Excellent point. I hadn't thought of that. A private member function should have the same effect at less space cost.